# How can show a number in a format translation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello everybody I did use jquery to traslate NUMBERS TO WORDS.

Here is the view and demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ7R4/47/)

```
<form>
 Number to words<BR>
 <BR>Number/N&uacute;mero 
 <INPUT NAME="Number" TYPE="number" SIZE="60" value="123"> <BR><TEXTAREA NAME="Spanish" ROWS="5" COLS="90"></TEXTAREA><BR>
</form>
```

And this will show:

```
CIENTO VEINTITRES CON /100 NUEVOS SOLES
```

But I want to show (when it has no point symbol)

```
CIENTO VEINTITRES CON 00/100 NUEVOS SOLES
```

The other problem is the symbol point is not working correctly, for example in this line:

```
<INPUT NAME="Number" TYPE="number" SIZE="60" value="123.12"> <BR>
```

I should have

```
CIENTO VEINTITRES CON 12/100 NUEVOS SOLES
```

I tried this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ7R4/48/)

Can someone point out what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start at the top of the second function by `splitting` the number at the decimal, if there's one, with the following code:

```
    var cents = s.split('.')[1] || '00',
        s = s.split('.')[0] || s;
```

Then change `Number` in the line pointed out by @Halcyon to `cents` (line 143):

```
    return (result+" CON "+ cents +"/100 NUEVOS SOLES");
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/RQ7R4/51/)

Comment: OMG you are really really awesome...thank you so much mister you won points and my respect

Comment: You might need to tweak a few lines such as `if (s + cents=='000') {return ('CERO');}` if some one enter 0.12 .... Glad I could help ... Thanks and enjoy :)

Comment: Right now if you enter `0.13` for example it will treat that as `CERO` -- try it (my demo). To make the comparison fair use `s + cents` which will combine `0` with `13` and it wont return `CERO`. Hope that helps.

Comment: How about setting `input` type to `text` so it can accept non-numeric input such as `comma`? Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/RQ7R4/74/

Comment: OMG seems that you read my mind =) thank you wherever you are =)

Comment: Hello bro, Can you help me with this please? Seems not to be working at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689571/jquery-converting-to-words-is-not-working-correctly

Comment: Yes bro, I'd be delighted to assist ... if you can create a new question regarding the issue with `UN MIL...` instead of `MIL ...` I'll take a look.

Comment: I did it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689571/jquery-converting-to-words-is-not-working-correctly