# Jquery converting to words is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a query that will traslate numbers to words.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/RQ7R4/84/) working fine with value from 1 until 1,999.99:

```
<form>
 Number to word<BR>
 Number/Número
 <INPUT NAME="Number" TYPE="text" SIZE="60" value="1,658.12"> <BR><TEXTAREA NAME="Spanish" ROWS="5" COLS="90"></TEXTAREA><BR>
</form>
```

But the problem is that is not working when using the comma

When I try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/RQ7R4/85/):

```
<INPUT NAME="Number" TYPE="text" SIZE="60" value="2,658.12"/>
```

I should get DOS MIL SEISCIENTOS CINCUENTA Y OCHO CON 12/100 NUEVOS SOLES

Also when I try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/RQ7R4/88/)

```
<INPUT NAME="Number" TYPE="text" SIZE="60" value="12,658.12"/>
```

I should get DOCE MIL SEISCIENTOS CINCUENTA Y OCHO CON 12/100 NUEVOS SOLES

And finally [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/RQ7R4/89/)

```
<INPUT NAME="Number" TYPE="text" SIZE="60" value="112,658.12"/>
```

I should get CIENTO DOCE MIL SEISCIENTOS CINCUENTA Y OCHO CON 12/100 NUEVOS SOLES

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: Try writing the routine so that a comma isn't accounted for.  If you get outside of Spanish (and English for that matter), you'll find that a comma isn't what you expect.  Standardize the number, then parse accordingly.

Comment: Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/RQ7R4/94/ .. let me know if it works.

Comment: Please I asked this to another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700380/translating-input-value-issue

Comment: Thanks it worked, you are still the best but why didn't you add here as answer?, thank you master!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need one line of code to fix it *(place this right below `//Spanish words for numbers`)*

```
s = s.replace(',','');
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/75pYq/) with your 1st test case pre-filled

Comment: Is working but when I write 1,658.12 is SHOWING "UN MIL..." and should be "MIL..."

Comment: @ThanatosSama There's this on line 61 of the fiddle: `if (a==1){result='UN '+result;}`. You should probably remove that line if you don't what that to happen, also updating the `else if` below it to just use `if`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/75pYq/2/)

Comment: Ok if you remove if (a==1){result='UN '+result;} all words from 1 to 999 will be affected.

Comment: @ThanatosSama This is not part of the original question, and it's not related to it in any way. You need to alter your comparisons to check if you should add it or not, but this does not fall under the scope of the comma problem. Please try fixing it yourself or post a separate question.